# How exactly does mDNS resolve addresses?

Tags: bonjour, jmdns, mdns, dns-sd

Once a service is discovered through DNS-SD, how exactly does the address of that host get resolved, and does it take significantly more time/overhead?

Also, if I am using JmDNS or Bonjour there are call-backs for both `serviceFound` and `serviceResolved`. If I am just interested in the IP address of the device publishing a certain service, is there a faster/more efficient way of getting the address than going through both `serviceFound` and `serviceResolved`?

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

DNS-SD uses Multicast DNS (MDNS) which works by sending DNS packets over UDP to a certain multicast address. All mdns-capable hosts in the network also listen to this address. It uses UDP so, it's quite low overhead. Also, the clients are designed in a way that the amount of chatter on the network is kept to a minimum, by using extensive caching.

Service discovery is a two step process. The first step is finding the names of all hosts providing a certain service (e.g. printing). This will not yet give you the ip address, instead it gives you the mdns name (ending with `.local`). This is because the ip could possibly change, whereas the name will not.

The second step in service discovery is to resolve the `.local` name of the host over mdns. You ask via multicast who `foo.local` is, `foo.local` will see that packet, and respond via broadcast with its ip address, port number and other information.

Comment: Please help with this query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662608/service-discovery-using-dns-sd